# get TomSelect dropdown box width bigger than top select box?

Tags: javascript, tom-select

Would aonyone know how I can get the dropdown box in Tom Select to be biger than the top select box, i'm trying to use w-auto but the text in the dropdown box is then "cut off" as some of the text is smaler than the text in the top start/select box

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS:

```css
.ts-dropdown{
   width: <your desired width: 100px, 10em...>
}
```